# SubQuery using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am using a LINQ subquery to obtain all the words of minimum length in an array.
I want to do it using Lambda Expression.

```
var names = new[] { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Mary", "Jay" }.AsQueryable();
(
from n in names
where n.Length == names.Min (n2 => n2.Length)
select n
)
```

Output :
 Tom , Jay

Thanks,
Prakhar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question to me seems a little bit vague, but is this what you're looking for?

```
 names.Where (x => x.Length == names.Min (n2 => n2.Length));
```

Answer (score 6):

This would work:

```
var minNames = names.Where(s => s.Length == names.Min(n=>n.Length));
```

But it evaluates the min length for every name in list (`O(n*n)` complexity), therefore this would be better:

```
var min = names.Min(s => s.Length); //calc. this only once
var minNames = names.Where(s => s.Length == min);
```

Comment: Upvoted. See the interesting linked thread which confirms that `Min` method is called each time, leading to `O(n**2)` complexity just like you say. Another way to tackle this is `int min = int.MaxValue; var minNames = names.OrderBy(s => s.Length).TakeWhile(s => min >= (min = s.Length))` but that is hardly better than your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
    var minNames = names.Where(c => c.Length == names.Min(n => n.Length))
            .ToArray();
```